# How do you add a file to an existing project in Codelite?

Tags: c++, codelite

I've got my workspace, project and a single file currently. I want to add an additional file to my src folder but can't figure out how.

I tried adding a new file to my project folder using ctrl+N and it shows up with my first file when I go to Edit -> Open file. However, it won't show up in my src folder while I've got my workspace/project open; that part is still only showing the original file I created when I made the project.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the `src` folder and select `Add an existing file`

[image: Add an existing file]

Comment: Is there a Keyboard Shortcut for this?

Comment: No, there is no keyboard shortcut for this

Comment: Add a feature request (maybe Shift-Ctrl-N)?

Comment: @Eran How can there *NOT* be a hotkey for adding a file to project? In which imaginable universe does it make sense to not have a hotkey for adding a file to a project? In the universe of free and open-source software of course!