# build error in c++, undefined symbols, tried other answers here, cant figure it out

Tags: c++, build

my code compiles fine but i get this error upon build.
i understand that something is out of whack with the symbol defs, but ive gone over and over them and from what i see, they are all defined correctly and have the correct references so im thinking maybe its a problem with the way ive put the header and implementation together, but idk. help please, please dont shut it down just because the question has been asked, i didnt get any help from other answers to other questions.

```
/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/make -j4 -e -f  Makefile'
----------Building project:[ AreaComp - Debug ]----------
/usr/bin/g++ -o ./Debug/AreaComp @"AreaComp.txt" -L.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"compute::Area::compSq()", referenced from:
  _main in Areamain.cpp.o
"compute::Area::compHex()", referenced from:
  _main in Areamain.cpp.o
"compute::Area::compOct()", referenced from:
  _main in Areamain.cpp.o
"compute::Area::compTri()", referenced from:
  _main in Areamain.cpp.o
"compute::Area::compHept()", referenced from:
  _main in Areamain.cpp.o
"compute::Area::compPent()", referenced from:
  _main in Areamain.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see    invocation)
make[1]: *** [Debug/AreaComp] Error 1
make: *** [All] Error 2
====1 errors, 0 warnings====
```

here's the header file:

```
 #ifndef MAIN_SAVITCH_COMPUTE_H
 #define MAIN_SAVITCH_COMPUTE_H

namespace compute
{
     class Area
     {
     public:

         void compTri();
         void compSq();
         void compPent();
         void compHex();
         void compHept();
         void compOct();

     private:

         double area;

     };

 }
 #endif
```

Here's Implementation (tried as .cxx and .cpp....no change):

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <cassert>
 #include "Area.h"



namespace compute
{

double i;

void Area::compTri()
{
    for(i = 1.00; i < 6.00; i++)
    {
        area = (1.00/2.00)i*((pow((-(1/2)i), 2.00)+pow(i,2.00)));

        cout<< "area for triangle of side length"<< i << "=" << area << endl;
    }
}
void Area::compSq()
{
    for(i = 1.00; i < 6.00; i++)
    {
        area = 2.00*i;

        cout << "area for square of side length" << i << "=" << area << endl;
    }
}
void Area::compPent()
{
    for(i = 1.00; i < 6.00; i++)
    {
        area = (1.00/4.00)*sqrt(5.00*(5.00 + 2.00*sqrt(5.00)))*pow(i,2.00);

        cout << "area for pentagon of side length" << i << "=" << area << endl;
    }
}
void Area::compHex()
{
    for(i = 1.00; i < 6.00; i++)
    {
        area = ((3.00*sqrt(3.00))/2.00)*pow(i,2.00);

        cout << "area for hexagon of side length" << i << "=" << area << endl;
    }
}
void Area::compHept()
{
    for(i = 1.00; i < 6.00; i++)
    {
        area = (7.00/4.00)*pow(i,2.00)*(1.00/tan(180.00/7.00));

        cout << "area for heptagon of side length" << i << "=" << area << endl;
    }
}
void Area::compOct()
{
    for(i = 1.00; i < 6.00; i++)
    {
        area = 2.00*(1.00+sqrt(2.00))*pow(i,2.00);

        cout << "area for octagon of side length" << i << "=" << area << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

here's the main file:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cassert>
 #include <cmath>
 #include "Area.h"

 using namespace std;
 using namespace compute;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

int a;

cout <<"this program will compute the area of a polygon with between 3 & 8"<< endl;


cout << "how many sides does your polygon have?" << endl;


cin >> a;


assert(a >= 3 && a <= 8);


Area find;



if(a == 3)
{
    find.compTri();
}
else if(a == 4)
{
    find.compSq();
}
else if(a == 5)
{
    find.compPent();
}
else if(a == 6)
{
    find.compHex();
}
else if(a == 7)
{
    find.compHept();
}
else
{
    find.compOct();
}

return 0;
};
```

make file:

```
 ##
 ## Auto Generated makefile by CodeLite IDE
 ## any manual changes will be erased      
 ##
 ## Debug
 ProjectName            :=AreaComp
 ConfigurationName      :=Debug
 WorkspacePath          := "/Users/tuckerfowler/Documents/CS3304"
 ProjectPath            := "/Users/tuckerfowler/Documents/CS3304   /AreaComp"
 IntermediateDirectory  :=./Debug
 OutDir                 := $(IntermediateDirectory)
 CurrentFileName        :=
 CurrentFilePath        :=
 CurrentFileFullPath    :=
 User                   :=Tucker Fowler
 Date                   :=18/01/2016
 CodeLitePath           :="/Users/tuckerfowler/Library/Application     Support/codelite"
 LinkerName             :=/usr/bin/g++
 SharedObjectLinkerName :=/usr/bin/g++ -dynamiclib -fPIC
 ObjectSuffix           :=.o
 DependSuffix           :=.o.d
 PreprocessSuffix       :=.i
 DebugSwitch            :=-g 
 IncludeSwitch          :=-I
 LibrarySwitch          :=-l
 OutputSwitch           :=-o 
 LibraryPathSwitch      :=-L
 PreprocessorSwitch     :=-D
 SourceSwitch           :=-c 
 OutputFile             :=$(IntermediateDirectory)/$(ProjectName)
 Preprocessors          :=
 ObjectSwitch           :=-o 
 ArchiveOutputSwitch    := 
 PreprocessOnlySwitch   :=-E
 ObjectsFileList        :="AreaComp.txt"
 PCHCompileFlags        :=
 MakeDirCommand         :=mkdir -p
 LinkOptions            :=  
 IncludePath            :=  $(IncludeSwitch). $(IncludeSwitch). 
 IncludePCH             := 
 RcIncludePath          := 
 Libs                   := 
 ArLibs                 :=  
 LibPath                := $(LibraryPathSwitch). 

 ##
 ## Common variables
 ## AR, CXX, CC, AS, CXXFLAGS and CFLAGS can be overriden using an environment variables
 ##
 AR       := /usr/bin/ar rcu
 CXX      := /usr/bin/g++
 CC       := /usr/bin/gcc
 CXXFLAGS :=  -g -O0 -Wall $(Preprocessors)
 CFLAGS   :=  -g -O0 -Wall $(Preprocessors)
 ASFLAGS  := 
 AS       := /usr/bin/as


 ##
 ## User defined environment variables
 ##
 CodeLiteDir:=/Users/tuckerfowler/Downloads/codelite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/
 Objects0=$(IntermediateDirectory)/main.cpp$(ObjectSuffix) 



 Objects=$(Objects0) 

 ##
 ## Main Build Targets 
 ##
 .PHONY: all clean PreBuild PrePreBuild PostBuild MakeIntermediateDirs
 all: $(OutputFile)

 $(OutputFile): $(IntermediateDirectory)/.d 
 $(Objects) 
 @$(MakeDirCommand) $(@D)@echo "" > $(IntermediateDirectory)/.d
 @echo $(Objects0)  > $(ObjectsFileList)
 $(LinkerName)
 $(OutputSwitch)
 $(OutputFile)
 @$(ObjectsFileList)
 $(LibPath) 
 $(Libs) 
 $(LinkOptions)

 MakeIntermediateDirs:
 @test -d ./Debug || $(MakeDirCommand) ./Debug


 $(IntermediateDirectory)/.d:
 @test -d ./Debug || $(MakeDirCommand) ./Debug

 PreBuild:


 ##
 ## Objects
 ##
 $(IntermediateDirectory)/main.cpp
 $(ObjectSuffix):main.cpp
 $(IntermediateDirectory)/main.cpp
 $(DependSuffix)
 $(CXX)
 $(IncludePCH)
 $(SourceSwitch) "/Users/tuckerfowler/Documents/CS3304/AreaComp/main.cpp"
 $(CXXFLAGS)
 $(ObjectSwitch)
 $(IntermediateDirectory)/main.cpp
 $(ObjectSuffix) 
 $(IncludePath)
 $(IntermediateDirectory)/main.cpp
 $(DependSuffix): main.cpp
 @$(CXX)
 $(CXXFLAGS)
 $(IncludePCH)
 $(IncludePath)-MG-MP-MT
 $(IntermediateDirectory)/main.cpp
 $(ObjectSuffix) -MF 
 $(IntermediateDirectory)/main.cpp
 $(DependSuffix) -MM "main.cpp"

  $(IntermediateDirectory)/main.cpp  
  $(PreprocessSuffix): main.cpp
  @$(CXX) 
  $(CXXFLAGS)
  $(IncludePCH)
  $(IncludePath)
  $(PreprocessOnlySwitch)
  $(OutputSwitch)
  $(IntermediateDirectory)/main.cpp
  $(PreprocessSuffix) "main.cpp"


 -include $(IntermediateDirectory)/*$(DependSuffix)
 ##
 ## Clean
 ##
 clean:
  $(RM) -r ./Debug/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your makefile. You're not linking with the implementation. If you post the Makefile I can help further.

Right solution:
[How to link multiple implementation files in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622409/how-to-link-multiple-implementation-files-in-c)

Other alternatives:

- Include the implementations .cpp file in the main file (don't recommend it, but it'll work)
- Cut/paste the implementations .cpp file into the main file (equivalent to above, but not scalable)

Comment: I've never used CodeLite, but I know you need to add your implementation file to your project. I found an SO for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32327212/how-do-you-add-a-file-to-an-existing-project-in-codelite

Comment: Nowhere in that makefile does it mention your implementation file. Since the makefile was generated by codelite, you'll have to add it through codelite. See my previous comment

Comment: actually i just figured it out, while the files were in the correct pathway, they werent reconciled into the src folder, one reconciled in codelite it worked like a charm....jesus h christ what a night

Comment: Haha. Yeah it can be a pain at times; not intuitive at all. Good luck with everything